# In GHCi, what is the difference between ':module' and 'import'?

Tags: haskell, ghci

In GHCi, there appear to be two ways to include installed modules:

```
Prelude> :module Database.HDBC
Prelude Database.HDBC>
```

and

```
Prelude> import Database.HDBC
Prelude Database.HDBC>
```

Is there any difference between these? If not, why the duplicate commands?

I've always used `import`, and now am noticing `:module` used in [Real World Haskell's databases chapter](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-databases.html).

Comment: I think RWH was written before ghci supported import statements.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [GHCi docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#controlling-what-is-in-scope-with-the-module-command):

> The `:module` command provides a way to do two things that cannot be
>   done with ordinary `import` declarations:
>
> - `:module` supports the `*` modifier on modules, which opens the full top-level scope of a module, rather than just its exports.
> - Imports can be removed from the context, using the syntax `:module -M`. The `import` syntax is cumulative (as in a Haskell module), so this is the only way to subtract from the scope.